# Pass the value form razor class library component to ASP.NET Core MVC controller

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, blazor

I have the following scenario RCL which has a component that component contains drop-down list "Years".

When selecting the year from DDL, I want the selected value to be passed to the controller in the ASP.NET Core MVC web application.

Comment: So what have you done so far?  RCL, DDL define?

Comment: I created the razor component inside the RCL and add the RCL as a reference in the MVC web application what I want in the drop-down change event is to pass the year value to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you would want to separate the controller from the service which performs work. Then you would inject this service where needed, instead of using the controller directly:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0

But if the controller is a separate application, then generate a client for the api first and inject that client where needed:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0